# Javascript regex "Invalid group"?

Tags: javascript, appcelerator-titanium

i am trying to make javascript username verify regex

```
' ^(?=.{4,16}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$
'  └─────┬────┘└───┬──┘└─────┬─────┘└─────┬─────┘ └───┬───┘
'        │         │         │            │           no _ or . at the end
'        │         │         │            │
'        │         │         │            allowed characters
'        │         │         │
'        │         │         no __ or _. or ._ or .. inside
'        │         │
'        │         no _ or . at the beginning
'        │
'        username is 4-16 characters long
```

when i am using it on Titanium Appcelerator i got this error

```
[ERROR] :  Error generating AST for "***register.js"
[ERROR] :  Invalid regular expression: /^(?=.{4,16}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/: Invalid group
[ERROR] :  Alloy compiler failed
```

my code :

```
var regex = /^(?=.{4,16}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/;

        if ( !regex.test(e.value)) 
         {
            inputs.Username.borderColor = 'red';
            inputs.Username.backgroundColor = '#edcaca';
            return false;
         }
```

> any idea why its giving error invalid group ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
/^(?=.{4,16}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-z0-9._]+[a-z0-9]$/i
```

Or avoiding most of the lookaheads:

```
/^(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-z0-9][a-z0-9._]{2,14}[a-z0-9]$/i
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/gH3cF0/5)

The problem is that lookbehinds (positive `(?<=...)` and negative `(?<!...)`) are not supported by JavaScript.

Comment: solution + explanation of issue , best answer ,,,, thanks :) u mad my day

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers I'm happy it helped you :-). Usually a lookbehind can be avoided as I did above.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript's regex engine doesn't support [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?<![_.])`.

Comment: i didn't understand by " doesn't support lookbehind " , u mean this part ? `(?![_.])`

Comment: `(?<!...)` is a negative lookbehind, which is not supported unfortunately.